# Clustering for DomIcon

Tags: html, here-api

I am trying to make clusters of `H.map.DomMarker`, which are using `H.map.DomIcon` with the HTML code. But the native Here Map clustering doesn't work. Only if I use simple `H.map.Icon`, but as this is rendered as a `canvas` layer, I cannot use my own markers.

Is there any way how to get clusters on `DomIcon`?

Edit:
Also, is there any way how to get list of markers inside cluster?

Thanks
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible using the code from [Map clustering with custom theme](https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/v3.0/clustering/custom-cluster-theme), because the clustering itself is agnostic to the resulting icon.

The first key part of the clustering in the example is to create a collection of `H.clustering.DataPoint(item.latitude, item.longitude, null, item)` which contains lat, lon. The clustering is based on those coordinates, and on the algorithm configuration.
The other key part is the theme itself which contains two function definitions:

- `getClusterPresentation` which is responsible for returning the `H.map.Marker` of points clustered together
- `getNoisePresentation` which is responsible for returning the `H.map.Marker` of non clustered points

Since `H.map.DomMarker` is a `H.map.Marker`, having the two above functions returning `H.map.DomMarker` should work.

> Is there any way how to get list of markers inside cluster

Yes. When you create the marker for the cluster, in `getClusterPresentation`, you get the points which are being clustered together (see `cluster.forEachDataPoint` function). And before, when you create the datapoints, you had the chance to store data in it. So it is a good time to get data from those datapoints being clustered together, and reference it in the cluster marker if necessary.

Hope it makes sense!

**Additionally**

> [...] if I use simple H.map.Icon, but as this is rendered as a canvas layer, I cannot use my own markers

Actually you can do all of the above with `H.map.Icon` and markers rendered in the canvas. Some things are a bit less obvious though, like setting a pointer cursor when hovering on a cluster or a noisepoint.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's working now. The only thing I still can't figure out is how to dynamically render (according the zoom) the number of markers in the cluster.

Comment: Cool! You may want to use `cluster.getWeight()`, which returns the number that you're looking for, and somehow integrate it to the markup of your icon.

Comment: Thanx for that. `cluster.getWeight()` did the job. Here Map is little bit complicated than Leaflet for me:)