# Slow updating HereMaps DomIcon when location (lat / long) changes, re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, here-api

Using `renderToStaticMarkup` to render html to a `DomIcon` in HereMaps. That's working and quick when there's not that many markers and updates. However, 100 markers frequently updating and re-rendering is causing a slow page open. It's even slowing the map render.

I've looked into [best practices around re-using a DomIcon](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/best-practices.html). I've [also been looking into clustering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52724857/clustering-for-domicon/52730341#52730341) -- but not sure how updating would work. Is clustering the only way to go further here? Curious if there's any other best practices for performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clustering solves the potential performance issues, however H.map.Group is used to associate the markers together and the group.getBounds() method to find the minimal bounding box holding all of the group's contents. The map.viewBounds() can then be updated.

```
function addMarkersAndSetViewBounds() {
  // create map objects
  var toronto = new H.map.Marker({lat:43.7,  lng:-79.4}),
      boston = new H.map.Marker({lat:42.35805, lng:-71.0636}),
      washington = new H.map.Marker({lat:38.8951, lng:-77.0366}),
      group = new H.map.Group();

  // add markers to the group
  group.addObjects([toronto, boston, washington]);
  map.addObject(group);

  // get geo bounding box for the group and set it to the map
  map.getViewModel().setLookAtData({
    bounds: group.getBoundingBox()
  });
}
```

forEachDataPoint (callback)

This method invokes the specified callback for each data point in the given cluster which can work for updating the data points.

> A clustering algorithm groups data points by collapsing two or more
>   points positioned close to one another on the screen into a single
>   cluster point. All other (not collapsed) points are still visible on
>   map as noise points.

If this actually suits the use case, go for clustering. It helps to uplift the performance issue. for more details refer : 
developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/clustering.html

Comment: So a marker within the group is updated. Then the rest of the markers can essentially still affect the bounding box. Basically, the group persists even when a marker is updated. I don't want to recreate the markers each time there's one update. That makes sense about the groups.